# Android app unable to post details to url

Tags: java, php, android, restful-url

I have an Android app that posts to "http://jont.byethost3.com/gcmtest/gcm.php?shareRegId=true". Once that is accessed, the app posts an id key to the script and the php file saves it to a textfile on my file server.
I have manually entered the url into my browser and it successfully generated an empty text file due to not receiving any POST data but when I test it on my app, it doesn't work.

I use Asynchttp to call and pass the data like this

```
private void backgroundRegister(final String username){
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>(){

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String msg = "";
            try{

                if(gcmObj==null){
                    gcmObj = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                }
                registerID = gcmObj.register(AppConstants.PROJ_ID);
                msg = "Registration ID : " + registerID;
                Log.d("REGOID",registerID);

            }catch(IOException e){
                Log.d("IOEXCEPTION",e.toString());
            }
            return msg;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(registerID)){
                savetoSharedPrefs(getApplicationContext(),registerID,username);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registered with GCM",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registration failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}

private void savetoSharedPrefs(Context context, String registerID,String userName){
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("userDetails", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(regID, registerID);
    editor.putString(userNAME, userName);
    editor.commit();
    storeREG();
}

//store in the file server (PHP)
private void storeREG(){

    pg.show();
    params.put("regID", registerID);
    //Make RESTful webservice call

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.post(AppConstants.SERVER_URL,params,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            pg.hide();
            if(pg!=null){
                pg.dismiss();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ID sharing successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent home = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class);
            home.putExtra("regID",registerID);
            Log.d("REGID",registerID);
            startActivity(home);
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            pg.hide();
            if(pg!=null){
                pg.dismiss();
            }
            if(statusCode==404){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Requested resource not found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else if(statusCode==500){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something went wrong at the server",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Unexpected error occurred",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }


    });

}
```

The data I want to pass is just plaintext. 
I hope someone can help me with this.

EDIT

My php script

```
if(!empty($_GET["shareRegId"])) {
    $gcmRegID  = $_POST["regID"]; 
    //echo $gcmRegID;
    file_put_contents("./GCMRegId.txt",$gcmRegID);
    echo "Done!";
    exit;
    }
```

My manifest just in case

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- GCM Permissions - Start here  -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


<permission android:name="com.example.amosang.pushtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />


<uses-permission android:name="com.example.amosang.pushtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <action android:name="com.example.amosang.pushtest" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".GCMNotificationIntentService" />
</application>
```

UPDATE : 
I have managed to get this code working  locally using my mamp server, the issue remains when i upload it to this host.

Comment: How you are passing the parameter here ? By appending to url ?

Comment: You are passing data to the URL both by appending to the url and by post? That's the problem i guess

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. I edited my code in the question. I pass the data through the params next to the url

Comment: I still haven't managed to solve this issue. Any form of testing using Postman or a Restful test client comes back with a 200 status code meaning OK.

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass **Post params** using `AsyncAndroidHttp` library you can use the provided `RequestParams` class and pass that to your `Post` API call, a little demonstration of what i mean :

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
RequestParams req = new RequestParams();
req.add("shareRegId","true");

client.post(AppConstants.SERVER_URL,req,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
        pg.hide();
        if(pg!=null){
            pg.dismiss();
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ID sharing successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent home = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class);
        home.putExtra("regID",registerID);
        Log.d("REGID",registerID);
        startActivity(home);
        finish();
    }
```

This will help you pass `Post Params`,

Comment: I have added my php script. It is supposed to use GET to check if the shareRegId is not empty and then from POST, get the data. So far it doesn't seem to be contacting the site at all.

Comment: The problem is that I have no idea if the client.post is able to send any information out aside from the textfile being created on the php side. At the moment all my permissions are correct but no text file has been generated

Comment: do one thing for a while change your `post` to `get` and in php script use `$_GET` to get both the params and see what happens

Comment: I changed it and tried to use get. However the fileserver doesn't seem to be receiving any connection from my app. Same result. Nothing happened. My manifests have been set to allow for internet. However when I copied that url and pasted it on my browser, the file could be created.

Comment: override `onFailure` method of `AsyncHttpResponseHandler ` and see if returns error

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any error. I'll post the entire code up in the question for you to see.

Comment: Would there be a difference if i used the standard HTTP request instead of this?

Comment: No there wouldn't be any, can you print your sever url with appended parameter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109104/discussion-between-jianya-and-satyen-udeshi).